# Apache Spark Accumulable addInPlace can see empty accumulables?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

This is a more conceptual "would Spark do this?" question. I am implementing a DropEvalAccumulableParam class extending the AccumulableParam class (in Java).

**When addInPlace gets run we are seeing some of our Accumulables coming back with values as if they were created with the zero method of DropEvalAccumulableParam but never had any values accumulated onto them.** Fair enough, I can adjust my code to handle these cases.

I am theorizing that Spark might create an Accumulable on an executor but then shift that task to another executor that has more free resources? Then when it comes time to merge all the copies of the Accumulable there might be some that were created but never "added to."

**Question Is: Does this sound like a Spark-like behavior? Would a "new untouched" Accumulable need to be merged back in with the other copies of itself?** I would like to be able to dig into the source code for Spark and get some idea where this happens to show my boss, but I suspect it's something in the job manager, not directly in the Accumulable methods.

FWIW Spark 1.6.0, Java, using standard Accumulable < DropTuple,DropResults >  (our classes) with a DropEvalAccumulableParam that extends AccumulableParam.

```
// Merge two accumulated values together. Is allowed to modify and return the first value for 
//efficiency (to avoid allocating objects).
@Override
public R addInPlace(R thisDropTuple, R otherDropTuple) {

  thisDropTuple.dropEvaluation.accumulate(otherDropTuple.dropEvaluation);
  return thisDropTuple;
}
```

EDIT: I am running a .foreach() on an existing RDD and in the foreach I am doing an operation and then use .add(result) to the accumulator, so perhaps the fact that I am not creating a new RDD makes Spark return an accumulator in all cases?

Hope that helps, I can post more code if that is helpful. FWIW in my Java class I am making an ArrayList of Accumulables, doing a for loop on that ArrayList, and then running the foreach on a RDD inside that loop and applying the result to each accumulator in the ArrayList. It's basically "add" every element of the RDD to the "running total" held in each accumulator. Just that "add" is not simple addition but instead a statistical analysis in sequence comparing each element in the RDD to a single element held in the Accumulables in the ArrayList.

Comment: If partition is empty then there won't any values merged into accumulator.

Comment: Thanks @zero323, so you are saying the addInPlace won't be called on the "copy" of the accumulator in that partition? Therefore I should not be seeing empty/zero values being merged?

Comment: I will edit the question to clarify that I am not creating a new RDD, so probably Spark sees every partition as being non-empty. Might be what's causing this behavior